# Duvida em consulta GroupBy e Checkbox - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Estou desenvolvendo em PHP na Framework Laravel 5.5 e tenho o seguinte código para criar meus checkboxes.

```
{{-- percorrendo a tabela para exibir os checks--}}
@foreach($permissoes as $keys => $dados_permissoes)                                                
    {{-- se o resto da divisão for par será exibido na coluna A --}}                           
    @if(!($keys % 2))
        <tr class="">    
            <td></td>             
            <td></td>   
            <td></td>      
            <td></td> 
            <td></td>                                                           
            <td class="">   
                {{-- verificando se o valor do campo permissoes_id  é igual ao campo Id (Tabela está com RightJoin) se form entra no IF --}}                                                    
                @if($dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id)                                                                                                                      
                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p> 
                    <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"></p>              
            </td>

                @else                                                                                
                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>             

            </td> 
                @endif  

    {{-- se não será exibido na coluna B --}}                                                                                             
    @else                                                
            <td></td>        
            <td class=""> 
                {{-- verificando se o valor do campo permissoes_id  é igual ao campo Id (Tabela está com RightJoin) se form entra no IF --}}                                  
                @if($dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id)                                                                                                                                                                                    
                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>             
                    <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"></p>              
            </td>

                {{-- se não for exibe o check desmarcado--}}                                                    
                @else                     
                    <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>
            </td> 
    @endif 
{{-- finalizando o foreach --}}
@endforeach
```

quando vou editar os dados, eu verifico e comparo o registro com o perfil(ID) e  através disso atribuo ou não checked ao checkbox, até ai funciona direitinho..

meu problema está acontecendo quando a tabela possui o mesmo registro com perfis diferentes, ou seja o mesmo registro mais de uma vez, vejam a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando eu acesso a tela de editar, está sendo exibido o checkbox duplicado( marcado e desmarcado) e para resolver fui na consulta e adicionei um `groupby`, mas não funcionou como eu esperava por que dessa forma o registro exibido é somente o que está desmarcado.

Por isso pergunto, sugestões de como resolver?

Abaixo o código do meu controller onde está a consulta

```
 public function edit($perfis_id)
    {
        //descriptografando o ID
        $perfis_id = decrypt($perfis_id); 


        // consulta para obter as informações de vínculo do perfil retornando o primeiro registro
        // aqui retorna um unico objeto
        $perfispermissoes = $this->perfispermissoes->where('perfis_id', '=', $perfis_id)
                                                   ->first();      


        // consulta para obter as informações de vinculo do perfil e permissão
        $permissoes = $this->perfispermissoes->rightjoin('permissoes', 'permissoes_id', '=', 'permissoes.id')                                             
                                             ->select('perfis_permissoes.*', 'perfis_permissoes.permissoes_id as id_perfis_permissoes', 'permissoes.id as id_permissoes', 'permissoes.nome')
                                             ->orderby('permissoes.nome')   
                                           //  ->groupby('permissoes.nome')                          
                                             ->get();   



        // Recuperando os dados do Perfil para Exibir no Combobox de filtro por Perfil  
        $perfis = $this->perfis->where('id', '=', $perfis_id)->first(); 

        // variavel com o titulo do form    
        $title = 'Altere as Permissões / Perfis Vinculados'; 
        // variavel com a descrição do form de edição
        $desc = 'Altere as permissões vinculadas ao perfil';

        return view('paineladmin.perfis_permissoes.insert-edit', compact('title', 'desc', 'perfispermissoes', 'perfis', 'permissoes', 'teste'));
    }
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver meu problema alterando a forma de realizar o `update` e o `insert` para que com isso eu possa utilizar um `where` e obter os registros corretamente.

No codigo anterior, estava gravando somente os `checkboxes` que realmente eram selecionados pelo usuário, por esse fato, na hora de "editar", não conseguia utilizar um `where` na consulta sql e isso ocasionava o erro de duplicar os registros em tela.

Como encontrei uma grande dificuldade em realizar isso vou postar todo o meu código aqui, para ajudar os iniciantes como eu.

**HTML da tela com 2 Colunas de Checkboxes criados dinamicamente (Único form tanto para insert como edit)**

```
{{--Tabela e CheckBox Permissões --}} 
<div class="panel panel-primary">                                    
    <div class="panel-body">   
        <h4 class="text-center">Marque as Permissões: </h4>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>      
                        <td></td>             
                        <td></td>   
                        <td></td>  
                        <td></td>    
                        <td></td>                       
                        <td class="">                   
                            <button class='btn btn-info' type='button' title='Todos' id='btnchk' ><i class='icon-large  icon-ok'></i>Marcar Todos</button>
                        </td>
                            <td></td>  
                        <td class="">                   
                            <button class='btn btn-info' type='button' title='Todos' id='btnchkdesmarcar' ><i class='icon-large  icon-ok'></i>Desmarcar</button>
                            </td>  
                    </thead>                                

                    @if(isset($perfispermissoes))                                                                                                      
                        {{-- percorrendo a tabela para exibir os checks--}}
                        @foreach($permissoes as $keys => $dados_permissoes) 
                                {{-- se o resto da divisão for par será exibido na coluna A --}}                           
                                @if(!($keys % 2))
                                    <tr class="">    
                                        <td></td>             
                                        <td></td>   
                                        <td></td>      
                                        <td></td> 
                                        <td></td>                                                           
                                        <td class="">   
                                            {{-- verificando se o valor do campo permissoes_id  é igual ao campo Id (Tabela está com RightJoin) se form entra no IF --}}                                                    
                                            @if($dados_permissoes->id_permissoes == $dados_permissoes->permissoes_id && $dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id)       

                                                <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p> 
                                                <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"></p>              
                                        </td>                                                                                                                                          

                                            @elseif($dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id && $dados_permissoes->cod_permissao == $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes)                                                                                                                                 

                                               <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>                 


                                        </td>                                                                                

                                            @endif


                                {{-- se não será exibido na coluna B --}}                                                                                             
                                @else                                                
                                        <td></td>        
                                        <td class=""> 
                                            {{-- verificando se o valor do campo permissoes_id  é igual ao campo Id (Tabela está com RightJoin) se form entra no IF --}}                                  
                                            @if($dados_permissoes->id_permissoes == $dados_permissoes->permissoes_id && $dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id)                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>             
                                                <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"></p>              
                                        </td>
                                            @elseif($dados_permissoes->perfis_id == $perfis->id && $dados_permissoes->cod_permissao == $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes)    
                                                 <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[{{$dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}]" id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id_permissoes }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>                     

                                        </td> 

                                            @endif      

                                    </tr> 
                                @endif                                                            
                        {{-- finalizando o foreach --}}
                        @endforeach                                                      
                    @else
                        {{-- percorrendo a tabela para exibir os checks--}}
                        @foreach($permissoes as $keys => $dados_permissoes)                                                
                                {{-- se o resto da divisão for par será exibido na coluna A --}}                           
                                @if(!($keys % 2))
                                    <tr class="">    
                                        <td></td>             
                                        <td></td>   
                                        <td></td>      
                                        <td></td> 
                                        <td></td>                                                           
                                        <td class="">                                                                                                                                                                  
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[]"  id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>             
                                            <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados[]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id }}"></p>              
                                        </td>                                                           
                                {{-- se não será exibido na coluna B --}}                                                                                             
                                @else                                                
                                        <td></td>        
                                        <td class="">                                                                                                                                                                      
                                            <p><input type="checkbox" class='chk' name="permissoes_id[]"  id="permissoes_id" value="{{ $dados_permissoes->id }}"> {{$dados_permissoes->nome}}</p>   
                                            <p><input type="hidden" class='chk' name="permissoes_id_desmarcados[]" id="permissoes_id" checked value="{{$dados_permissoes->id }}"></p>                        
                                        </td>                                                        

                                    </tr> 
                                @endif                                                           

                        {{-- finalizando o foreach --}}
                        @endforeach 
                    @endif                                            
                </table>   
            </div>
    </div> <!-- Panel body -->
</div>   <!-- Panel horizontal -->
```

a tela gerada será similar a essa utilizando bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CSS** - Trecho do codigo para deixar a barra lateral na horizontal

```
.conteudo-horizontal {
    display: block;    
    height: 87%;   
    margin-left: 13%;
}

.panel-primary{

    border-color:#23282e;
}
.panel-title.text-center{

    color: #e1ffff;
}

.panel.panel-horizontal {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
  /*  margin-left: 175px;*/
    border-color:#23282e!important; 
}

.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-heading,
.panel-primary>.panel-heading{

    background-color: #23282e;

}

.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-heading,
.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-body,
.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-footer {
    display: table-cell;


}

.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-heading,
.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-footer {
    width: 1%;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-heading {
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;

}

.panel.panel-horizontal>.panel-footer {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;


}
```

**Código do Controller**

```
public function create()
    {       

        // repassando o titulo da pagina em uma variavel    
        $title = 'Vincular Permissões ao Perfil';
        // repassando a descrição da pagina em variavel
        $desc  = 'Vincule as Permissões a um determinado perfil para conceder acesso aos seus usuários';

        $permissoes = $this->permissoes->all();

        $permissoes = $this->permissoes->orderBy('nome')->get();

        // consulta para obter as informações dos combos User_id e Perfis_id
        $perfis = $this->perfis->all();

        // retornando a view com as variaveis
        return view('paineladmin.perfis_permissoes.insert-edit', compact('title', 'desc', 'permissoes', 'perfis'));
    }

   public function store(PerfisPermissoesRequests $request)
    {
        // recebendo todos os dados do formulário    
        $dataForm = $request->all();  

        // repassando o valor do Id 
        $id_perfis = $dataForm['perfis_id'];

        /*************************** Verificando os dados que foram Marcados na Inclusão ****************/
        /***********************************************************************************************/

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array Diff
        $collection = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id_desmarcados']);

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array Diff
        $collection2 = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id']);

        // realizando a verificação atráves do Array Diff
        $diff = $collection->diffKeys($collection2);

        // aqui será retornado a diferenca entre os Arrays
        $diferenca = $diff->all();


        /////////// INSERT DOS DADOS COM CHECKBOX MARCADO ///////////     

            // percorrendo o campo permissoes id para armazenar os dados no array
            foreach($dataForm['permissoes_id'] as $data) {

                // repassando os valores para um array
                $dataSet = [

                    'perfis_id'       => $id_perfis,
                    'permissoes_id'   => $data, 
                    'cod_permissao'   => $data,                  

                ];

                // realizando o insert dos dados com checkbox marcado
                 $insert = $this->perfispermissoes->create($dataSet); 
            }



        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        /////////// INSERT DOS DADOS COM CHECKBOX DESMARCADO ///////////

        // verificando se a variavel possui valor para entrar no laço
        if(!empty($diferenca)){    

            // percorrendo o campo permissoes id para armazenar os dados no array
            foreach($diferenca as $data) {

                // repassando os valores para um array
                $dataSet2 = [

                    'perfis_id'       => $id_perfis,            
                    'permissoes_id'   => null, 
                    'cod_permissao'   => $data,
                ];


                // realizando o insert dos dados com checkbox desmarcado
                $insert = $this->perfispermissoes->create($dataSet2); 
            }

        }


        // if de verificação
        if($insert){
            // repassando a mensagem de sucesso
            $mensagem = $this->mensagem->msgCadastroSucesso();
            // redirecionando para a rota
            return redirect()->route('perfispermissoesIndex');

        }else{
            // repassando a mensagem de sucesso
            $mensagem = $this->mensagem->msgErroInsert();
            // redirecionando para a rota
            return redirect()->back();
        }     

    }


public function edit($perfis_id)
    {
        //descriptografando o ID
        $perfis_id = decrypt($perfis_id); 

        // consulta para obter as informações de vínculo do perfil retornando o primeiro registro
        // aqui retorna um unico objeto
        $perfispermissoes = $this->perfispermissoes->where('perfis_id', '=', $perfis_id)
                                                   ->first();      


        // consulta para obter as informações de vinculo do perfil e permissão
        $permissoes = $this->perfispermissoes->rightjoin('permissoes', 'cod_permissao', '=', 'permissoes.id')                                             
                                             ->select('perfis_permissoes.*','perfis_permissoes.cod_permissao', 'perfis_permissoes.permissoes_id as id_perfis_permissoes', 'permissoes.id as id_permissoes', 'permissoes.nome')
                                             ->where('perfis_id', '=', $perfis_id)
                                             ->orderby('permissoes.nome')
                                             ->get();      


        // Recuperando os dados do Perfil para Exibir no Combobox de filtro por Perfil  
        $perfis = $this->perfis->where('id', '=', $perfis_id)->first(); 

        // variavel com o titulo do form    
        $title = 'Altere as Permissões / Perfis Vinculados'; 
        // variavel com a descrição do form de edição
        $desc = 'Altere as permissões vinculadas ao perfil';

        return view('paineladmin.perfis_permissoes.insert-edit', compact('title', 'desc', 'perfispermissoes', 'perfis', 'permissoes', 'permissoescheck'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(PerfispermissoesRequests $request, $perfis_id)
    {
        // Descriptografando o ID
        $perfis_id = decrypt($perfis_id);

        // recebendo todos os dados do formulário    
        $dataForm = $request->all();  


        /*************************** Verificando os dados que foram DESMARCADOS *************************/
        /***********************************************************************************************/

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array DIFF
        $collection = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos']);

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array DIFF
        $collection2 = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id']);

        // realizando a verificação atráves do Array Diff
        $diff = $collection->diffKeys($collection2);

        // retornando a diferença para a variavel
        // aqui será retornado os dados que foram desmarcados.
        $diferenca = $diff->all();    

        // verificando se a variavel possui valor para entrar no laço
        if(!empty($diferenca)){
            // percorrendo os dados desmarcado para apagar 
            foreach($diferenca as $dif){

                // verificando os dados no banco
                // o metodo first retorna sempre o primeiro registro em objeto 
                $update = $this->perfispermissoes->where('permissoes_id','=', $dif)
                                                 ->where('perfis_id', '=', $perfis_id)->first();

                // limpando os valores do campo 'permissoes_id'
                $dataSet = [           

                   'permissoes_id' => null,

                ];

                // realizando o update na tabela e desmarcando o campo
                $update = $update->update($dataSet);

            }       


        }

        /*************************** Verificando os dados que foram MARCADOS****************************/
        /***********************************************************************************************/

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array DIFF
        $collection = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id']);

        // repassando os dados para a variavel collection para verificar com Array DIFF
        $collection2 = collect($dataForm['permissoes_id_desmarcados_novos']);

        // realizando a verificação atráves do Array Diff
        $diff = $collection->diffKeys($collection2);

        // retornando a diferença para a variavel
        // aqui será retornado os dados que foram desmarcados.
        $novosregistros = $diff->all();

        // verificando se a variavel possui valor para entrar no laço
        if(!empty($novosregistros)){

            // percorrendo o campo do id
            foreach($novosregistros as $novosregistros) {

                 // verificando os dados no banco
                // o metodo first retorna sempre o primeiro registro em objeto 
                $update = $this->perfispermissoes->where('cod_permissao','=', $novosregistros)
                                                 ->where('perfis_id', '=', $perfis_id)->first();

                // repassando os valores para um array 
                // aqui vai setar o valor no campo atraves do array
                $dataSet = [

                    'permissoes_id' => $novosregistros,

                ];

                // realizando o update e marcando o campo
                $update = $update->update($dataSet);

            }


        }

        // laço de verificação
        if (isset($update)){
            $mensagem = $this->mensagem->msgAtualizadoSucesso();
            return redirect()->route('perfispermissoesEdit', encrypt($perfis_id)); 


        }else{
            $mensagem = $this->mensagem->msgErroEdit();
            return redirect()->route('perfispermissoesEdit', encrypt($perfis_id));    

        }

    }
```

Bom basicamente eu fiz isso :

**INSERT**
Ao enviar o formulário depois de preenchido, envio também um checkbox oculto do tipo (hidden) marcado.

feito isso verifico com `array diff` os cheks que estão marcados e desmarcados.
a partir daí faço a inclusão no banco.
Também criei um campo de nome `cod_permissao` na tabela para gravar o id da permissão para que com isso eu consiga obter os valores desse campo no edit quando utilizar o `RightJoin` (o codigo está comentado)

**Editar** 
No update eu fiz praticamente a mesma coisa
Ao acessar a tela utilizo um `if` que verifica quais checks foram marcados ou não e no meu controller faço uma consulta utilizando `RightJoin` para unir a tabela através do campo `cod_permissao` e a partir daí utilizo o `where` para filtrar por perfil
aí quando vou enviar o formulário para atualizar os registros, uso novamente `ArrayDiff` para verificar os campos marcados e desmarcados para depois realizar o `update` no banco de dados.

bom é isso espero que consigam entender.

Obrigado a todos